# Can't Load user picture on cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

Hello I'm having trouble loading users' pictures on my web page.

[cloudinary display error on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US4vQ.png)

When I check my Cloudinary account I can't find the picture.

res.cloudinary.com/di7e0fdiq/image/upload/v1498636677/rj2ijo3yb6yvmyrybnps.jpg

Here is my code: I'm using a helper to display users' pictures. I call this helper in my show:

```html
  def user_picture_avatar(user, image_class)
   if user.photo?
    cl_image_tag(user.photo.path, class: image_class)
   else
    avatar_url = user.linkedin_picture_url || "http://placehold.it/100x100"
    image_tag avatar_url, class: image_class
   end
  end
```

I tested the code directly in my show without using the helper as well and I have the same result.

```html
<!-- avatar display using helper -->
  <div class="user-show-photo">
    <%= user_picture_avatar(current_user, "interview-show-avatar avatar-bordered-xl") %>
  </div>

  <!-- avatar display without helper -->
  <div class="user-show-photo">
    <%= cl_image_tag @user.photo.path, width: 400, height: 300, crop: :fill %>
  </div>
```

Here is what I get when I look at the inspector on my webpage:

[html on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJQRq.png)

I have reviewed my cloudinary, figaro, application.yml and strong params setup many times and can't seem to solve this problem.

Can you help?

Comment: hello, what is the value of `user.photo.path` and based on the documentation why are you using the path instead of just the image name `cl_image_tag("sample.jpg", :width => 100, :height => 150, :crop => :fill)`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at our logs we see that the image was indeed uploaded (the fact you received a link with a version number also indicates that) on June 28th,  07:57:59 UTC

However, we see that it was [destroyed](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy) two seconds after it's upload on 07:58:01 UTC

This usually means that there is a destroy call issued by mistake.

Comment: Yes that was exactly it! thank you for the tip it allowed me to identify enrouons code in my update function. I was actually updating twice in a row. So on the first update the picture was being uploaded correctly, then on the second update it was being destroyed  without being replaced!
I used binding.pry for debugging, really useful !